# Replace Layer image in Photoshop scripting

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

How can I replace the image in a layer? For a text layer I can easily do `doc.layerSets.getByName('title').textItem.contents = 'New Text'`. So my question is, is there something similar to `textItem` that works with images. something like `imageItem`. so I can replace the image in a layer?

Comment: So what's exactly is your problem? What doesn't work for you? What's your psd structure?

Comment: There's a group called 'images' Which has multiple layers and all layers contain an image. There' another layer called 'target'. I want to loop through the 'images' group and put each image in 'target' layer and export it

Comment: Please edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55660119/edit) if you want to add information to it. Is there a reason you can't just put the frame in the same PSD file and then toggle the visibility of the image layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to copy all image layers' contents from a group into a single target layer.

You could accomplish this with the *intuitive* way of iterating through the group art layers and in-place copying/pasting their contents to the target layer. This might seen trivial in the GUI, but programmatically, it's way [too complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27303337/260411).

Another way, and perhaps a more programmatic way, would be to just iterate through the group art layers, duplicate each layer and merge them with the target layer. I'll give you an example:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var target = doc.layers.getByName('target');
var group = doc.layerSets.getByName('images');
var gal = group.artLayers;

// Iterate through art layers from group "images"
for (var i = 0; i < gal.length; i++) {
  // Duplicate current layer and put it before the target layer
  var temp = gal[i].duplicate(target, ElementPlacement.PLACEBEFORE);

  // Merge the current layer with the target
  // (the target variable has to be updated because it's now a new merged layer)
  target = temp.merge();
}
```

This works fine with a simple art target layer. Now if your target layer is more complex (i.e. it has blending properties, masks and etc.) and you want to maintain that, you'll have to resort to the "paste in place" method linked above.

Comment: Is there some way I can get the extension of `gal[i]` to check if it is png or jpg?